# MEF2 and .NET Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control, mef

I've been reading around that MEF is alive and well and etc...
I also been reading that I only need to replace the `void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` for `IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` supplying my own container (in my case the MEF container)...

My problem is that i can't manage to find the correct `return`. You see, `CompositionHost` does not implement `IServiceCollection`...

Can anyone teach me how to use MEF2 as my container on a .NET Core webapi?

Comment: I know it was a long time ago but did you ever end of figuring this out?

Comment: actually i didn't... got sidetracked...

Comment: Thanks anyways for the response. It's a few years later and I still can't seem to find an example of MEF2 + ASP.NET Core working together.

Answer (score 2):

this seems old and i hope it's not too late :D

Here's what you need to do:

Pre requisite:[Eml.MefBootstrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Eml.MefBootstrapper/)

1. Implement IControllerActivator

```
//using System.Composition.Hosting;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
public class MefControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
{
       private readonly CompositionHost container;

       public MefControllerActivator(CompositionHost c) { container = c; }

       public object Create(ControllerContext c) => container.GetExport(c.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.AsType());

       public void Release(ControllerContext c, object controller) { }
}
```

2. Create your extension method. Sample:

```
//using Eml.ClassFactory.Contracts;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
//using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
//using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
//using System;

    public static class MefService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Call this in Startup.ConfigureServices.
        /// Use Mef to resolve controllers. Hooks with ApplicationStopping for Mef disposal.
        /// Already have a reference to Eml.MefBootstrapper. Remove references to Eml.MefBootstrapper when using this to avoid version mismatch.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceCollection"></param>
        /// <param name="bootstrapper"></param>
        public static IClassFactory AddMef(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Func<IClassFactory> bootstrapper)
        {
            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            // Create Mef container
            var classFactory = bootstrapper();

            //Register MefControllerActivator
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(new MefControllerActivator(classFactory.Container));

            //Graceful exit
            var appLifetime = serviceProvider.GetService<IApplicationLifetime>();
            var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

            appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
            {
                var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Global logger");

                logger.LogDebug("Disposing Mef...");
                Eml.Mef.ClassFactory.Dispose(classFactory);
            });

            return classFactory;
        }
    }
```

3. Create IServiceCollection extension to be used in Startup.cs

```
//using Eml.ClassFactory.Contracts;
//using Eml.Mef;
//using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
//using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
//using System;
//using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Composition.Hosting;
//using System.Composition.Hosting.Core;
//using Trackinator.Api.Helpers.Mef;
//using Trackinator.Infrastructure;

    public static class MefStartup
    {
        public static IClassFactory ConfigureMefService(this IServiceCollection services, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            return services.AddMef(() =>
            {
                // Register instances as shared.
                var instanceRegistrations = new List<Func<ContainerConfiguration, ExportDescriptorProvider>>
                {
                        r => r.WithInstance(loggerFactory)
                };

                // Create Mef container
                //return Bootstrapper.Init(Constants.ApplicationId, instanceRegistrations);
                var classFactory = Bootstrapper.Init(new List<string> { Constants.ApplicationId, "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR." }, instanceRegistrations);
                
                return classFactory;
            });
        }
    }
```

4. Add this line to Startup.cs

```
public static IClassFactory ClassFactory { get; private set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //..other codes
    ClassFactory = services.ConfigureMefService(LoggerFactory);

}
```

See sample implementation [here](https://github.com/EddLonzanida/TravelRepublic-Angular/blob/master/Hosts/TravelRepublic.Api/Startup.cs)

Good luck!